# How to recuperate field value in others forms in section template in Orbeon

Tags: xpath, orbeon

I have a section Template'Section_library',in 'Section_library' i have a field 'first-name' who recuperate the value field from another section in my form so i used this expression 
 `xxf:component-context()/root()/form/Section_TWO/mycontrol`.
this expression not worked totally,the recuperation is done when i try to write in this field 'first-name'. i want a solution that automatically recuperate the value within any interaction of user.
I find this issue #3008 but i didn't understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of 2016.2, there is no reliable and supported way for code inside a section template to access information about the form it is used in. This is by design, but there are reasonable use cases that call for a section template being able to access things from the "outer form", and you're correct pointing to [RFE 3008](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/3008). For now I'd recommend you follow this issue.

Comment: @Lebki, I also added a +1 from you on the RFE, and if your organization has a PE subscription, I'd recommend you contact us through your support channel, as the more customers need a certain feature, the more likely that feature is to be implemented, quickly ;).